# ajax is not working from inside of datatable in JSF2

Tags: ajax, jsf, datatable, jsf-2.2

I am calling ajax in  which is in  to execute tag outside of datatable but is not working and not identify outside tag id's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose both the table and the tag you want to execute are inside the `<h:form id="myForm">`, you can try `execute=":myForm:myTagID"`. If it doesn't work, open your page in Chrome then use the `Inspect Element` feature of Chrome to find out the tag's ID to execute.